How to Change the floating label font size of an MDCOutlinedTextField in Swift iOS
How can I change the floating label font size of an MDCOutlinedTextField in Swift for an iOS project?
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_OutlinedTextFields

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: MDCOutlinedTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTF: MDCOutlinedTextField!
}
}

create extension for use into multiple textfield.
extension MDCOutlinedTextField {
    
    func setCustomTextField() {
        let containerScheme = MDCContainerScheme()
        self.applyTheme(withScheme: containerScheme)
        
        self.label.text = self.placeholder
        self.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
    }
}


